# How to get the context root directory in Java EE 6 application from a POJO?

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, properties

I have a Java EE 6 application with JSF 2 and Tomcat 7. Now I have a POJO. This POJO should read a properties file. The properties file is is located in WEB-INF/classes. The current directory is the users home directory /home/myUser.

How does the POJO get the context's root directory or some similar path, so that it can read the properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/WEB-INF/classes` is just part of the classpath. You could obtain it as classpath resource by [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). In a webapplication, the best is to obtain the `ClassLoader` by [`Thread#getContextClassLoader()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader%28%29) of the current `Thread`.

So, in a nut:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));
```

Answer (score 0):

and one more thing
if you can have a POJO that can read a properties file...
i guess something is wrong in the preliminary design..
the P in POJO stands for Plain...

Comment: On the other hand, it can also be the term "POJO" that is been abused. This happens much more often than you'd think. Regardless, this should have been posted as a comment on the question, not as an answer. If you have earned enough reputation by posting real answers, you'll be able to post comments on other's questions/answers.